# how to get property nodes if the properties name is "frames"

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to get the property nodes after `properties name="frame"`.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(textBox1.Text);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(textBox1.Text);

XmlNodeList types = doc.GetElementsByTagName("type");
XmlNodeList dataTypes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("dataType");
XmlNodeList keys = doc.GetElementsByTagName("key");
XmlNodeList values = doc.GetElementsByTagName("value");
XmlNodeList readOnlys = doc.GetElementsByTagName("readOnly");

while (reader.Read())
{
    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "properties"))
    {
        if (reader.HasAttributes && reader.GetAttribute("name") == "frame")
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
            dataGridView1[0, ObjectCount].Value = reader.GetAttribute("name");
            for (int i = 0; i < types.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1[1, ObjectCount].Value = types[i].InnerText;
                dataGridView1[2, ObjectCount].Value = dataTypes[i].InnerText;
                dataGridView1[3, ObjectCount].Value = keys[i].InnerText;
                dataGridView1[4, ObjectCount].Value = values[i].InnerText;
                dataGridView1[5, ObjectCount].Value = readOnlys[i].InnerText;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to code.](https://pastebin.com/eTe9ev1r)

Actual: `0, 0, id, 14126acb21914ddf8e8f8d2b8f2c2ecf, 0`

Expected: `0, 1, index, 0, 0`

Comment: This should help you:[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//properties[@name='frame']/property");
```